# Push notification c# google code showing error "File not found" every time.?

Tags: c#, google-code, filenotfoundexception, apns-sharp

I need to use asp.net c# code for Server of Push notification Service. i have also downloaded Source code from google Source code. there are 3 zip files available . I am using latest Apns-Sharp-1.0.3.0.

but when I am testing it, it gives a "File not found" error every time for the p12 certificate.

The certificate is available at specified path also. I have also tried to read a simple text file and also try other paths also but ever time it gives same error of "File not found at xxxx path."

please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should denote the base directory for the program to spot the specific file.

```
string p12File = "yourp12filename.p12";
string p12FilePassword = "yourpassword";
string p12Filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, p12File);
```

This would solve your "File not found" problem.

Comment: APNS requires a secure connection, hense the p12 file ;)